What are common words in which written ‹i› is pronounced as the phoneme /ai/?

I am a Brazilian teacher of the English language for Brazilian high school students. In this sense, the draft of this table has helped me a lot. So, my question about examples was only because I would like to improve this table to help me and help my students.
It’s not complete, of course, but this table intends to provide a list which could allow learners to get a glimpse of the implied rules around “i” pronounced as /ai/. To state the obvious, the way this table works is that
the horizontal axis represents the letter or letters right before the “i” pronounced /ai/, and the vertical axis represents the letter or letters right after the “i” pronounced /ai/.
Please understand that I do not intend to build a “very large database” as one commenter mentioned. My aim is simply to gather answers to help me with day-to-day difficulties in teaching English pronunciation to Brazilian high school students.

To be clear, are you asking us to help fill out the table, one by one, or are you asking us for hints on how to use tools to help fill it out faster or automatically? What does it mean for you if there is a gap, that is, there is no word that has the 3-way sequence? Also, what -are- some of these implicit rules about interconsonantal /ai/?

This question pointed me to the CMU dictionary, a large text file of English words with pronunciations (in ARPAbet not IPA). I suggest you download the file and search for "AY".

I don't think the rules about whether a vowel is long or short depend much on the letters around it.

"giant" is in the wrong place, isn't it? I'll give you"foci" and "miasma", but I'm not sure this is a good fit here, despite being an interesting puzzle

Spelling in English is chaotic - there are rules but the rules have exceptions, and those exceptions have exceptions and on and on, with lots of one-off 'this follows its own rule'. Use @StuartF's suggestion and fill out a table automatically by look for all triples around 'AY'.

And @Greybeard,
I do not intend to build a "very large database". My aim is to help me with day to day difficulties in teaching pronunciation.
I am a Brazilian teacher of English Language for Brazilian high school students. In this sense, the draft this table has helped me a lot.
So, my question was only because I would like to improve this table. help me and help my students.
Sorry if it is of topic.
And Thanks .

The problem is that there is no set of rules here. As Prof. Lawler once said, any honest ESL teacher will tell you that English is like Chinese: you need to teach the spelling and pronunciation of each word separately, since there's no rule for predicting one from the other.

@alphabet It is misleading to say that there are no rules. Of -course- there are rules to the English spelling<->pronunciation mapping, it's just that there are lots of exceptions.

@vanderesende Oh I get it now... you really are trying to make a way to explain some ways to remember how to spell certain words given their pronunciation (or the other direction). I don't think the two lettersaround the sound is the best predictor of how to spell /ai/. The better rule is 'i' followed by a consonant and then a silent 'e'.

@Mitch .... where "consonant" could be more than one letter.  As in writhe.

This question deserves an answer, even a negative one, not just comments. So I am unilaterally reopening it and providing such an answer. Others are certainly welcome to provide their own actual answers.

I’m afraid you aren’t going to be able to do what you’re hoping to do with
this—for several concrete reasons. So this answer should be read as a frame
challenge. You’ve asked a question that cannot be reasonably answered in the
positive, only in the negative. So that’s what I will do here.
A fundamental problem with this whole idea is that sometimes two or more
different pronunciations exist for the same spelling.  Sometimes this
alternation completely changes the meaning of the word, as it does with
live, wind, and minute.  But other times changing the vowel does not change
which word was said, as we see with vitamin, primer, and Philistine.
Sometimes this difference is even regional or by register.
Another major problem with your system is that written inter-consonantal ‹i›
in English represents not two possible phonemes, but four:

the /ai/ phoneme — with phonetic allophones including [ɑj], [aj], [ɐj], [ʌj], [ʌɪ], [ɑɪ], [aɪ], [ɑ]
the /i/ phoneme — with phonetic allophones including [ij], [ɪj], [i], [iː]
the /ɪ/ phoneme — with phonetic allophones including [ɪ], [ᵻ], [ɨ], [ɛ], [ǝ]
the/ɚ/ phoneme — with phonetic allophones including [ɚ], [ɝ], [ǝ], [ɜ]

All of those occur in both stressed and unstressed positions. Native
Portuguese speakers in particular will have trouble distinguishing /i/ from
/ɪ/, and this is a critical difference to English speakers.
Even where patterns do exist, the mapping between writing and pronunciation
requires obversing more than merely a single letter written to either side
of that ‹i›. You will need to look for a so-called “silent ‹e›” in some cases.
You will also have to take into account stress and emphasis, because even though
all occur in both stressed and unstressed positions, a word that’s emphasized
may be pronounced differently without changing which word is said.
And, of course, there are many exceptions to all of this even when you do
find a legitimate pattern. And none of it applies if there is a vowel to one
side or the other of the written ‹i›.
Here is a short list of common words with phonemes indicated via a special
diacritic as a brief demonstration of the inescapable problems you cannot avoid.
I’ve encoded which one of the four phonemes applies on each use via
a specific ad-hoc diacritic:

Phonemic /ai/ is written í in this list.
Phonemic /i/ is written î in this list.
Phonemic /ɪ/ is written ì in this list.
Phonemic /ɚ/ is written ï in this list.

(If a written ‹i› corresponds to no vowel at all, then it is marked without a dot or any diacritic so that it is represented by ı in the list below.)

adrenalìne alpíne aubergîne Benedìctîne bínd bïrch bïrd bíro bïrth bítey
bìtty brìgantîne busıness caníne Catherìne chìmney chína chîno cïrcle cítatıon cíte
cìty clementíne columbíne combíne crìnolìne crystalìne declíne declìnatıon defíne defìnìtıon díno Dîno
dïrge dïrt dìvíne doctrìne doctrínal doctrìnal engìne ermìne fîlo fìn fíght fínd fíne fîno fïr
fïrm fïrst fíver flïrt gasolîne genuìne gìft gïrdle gïrl gïrth gìver grímy grìppy
grípy guîllotîne hìck híke híney hìnt híree Í Í’ll ìll ìmagìne ìntestìne
Íran Ìran Îranìan írate îrrìtate ìrrìtate ísle ívy kîlo kìn kínd Kïrby kïrk lífe lífer lílac lìly
líma Lîma lìmo Lîsa lìtho líve lìve lívely lìver Lìvy Líza machîne magazîne malígn malìgnant marîne
medìcìne medıcìne Mìckey mícro mìdî Míkey mìller mílo míme mìmeo mínd míne mìnî mìnt mínute
mìnute mïrth mîso nïrvana phí phî phìltrum phímosìs píne pínt pìty Plíny Plìny prímer prìmer prîmo
prìnt prìthee prìvy ravîne rhíno Ríley routîne sardîne shíny shïrk shïrt sígn
sílo sïr skïrt smïrk spíce spíky swïrl tangerîne tapïr thïrd thïrst thïrty
tìc tìnny tíny tíro turbìne twïrl urìne urínal urìnal Valentíne Valentîno vaselîne vìdeo
vïrgìn vïrtue vítamìn vìtamìn whíny whïrl whìsper wífí wíld Wìlma wínd wìnd
wíno zïrcon zìtty

If you look over that list, the only pattern that seems generally usable is
that you get phoneme 4 above, the r-colored vowel, when you have a
written ‹ir› following a consonant which is not immediately followed by a vowel, as in bird, fir, girl, sir, shirt, Kirby.
Trying to teach learners any other rule than at most this one alone would be
too complicated and full of exceptions for them to be able to learn. They
will come to understand the underlying patterns only after long exposure
to them. You cannot teach it from a chart like yours.
Again, this is only for inter-consonantal uses of written ‹i›. All bets are off
when there are adjacent vocalic letters, such as you find in words like
genius, ruin, join, against, afraid, aisle, eight, heifer, yield,
coercion, persuasion, exertion, waive, naïve.

I decided not to write an answer as this is pretty much a fool's errand. However, your answer is fine but just not very pedagogical. I put the Trim book in a comment, which I am willing to expand but I do not want to deal with a slew of uninformed dv's.
